# Protocol - Is it OK to write a long Comment as an Answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

Comment space is very short.

Sometimes I have a very long comment where I would like to have the same capabilities as are available for *Answers* (e.g., paste long lists, show code, figures, ...) in order for my comment to be understood.

I haven't done this yet but I could write the *Comment* as an *Answer* with the first line:

***"This is not an Answer but too long for a Comment"***

Is it permissable to write a *Comment* as an *Answer*?

---

Edit by Belisarius

Please upvote if you think it's OK, or downvote otherwise. So we can use this question as the "community consensus"

Comment: It seems to be a pretty common practice: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22This+is+not+an+Answer%22

Comment: It's fine for me to post something too long for comments as an answer. If you're uncomfortable with accruing rep for that, you can of course set it as CW.

Comment: An alternative is using a link to a picture of e.g. you *Mathematica* notebook.

Comment: I would not suggest doing this on StackOverflow, because there is no provision for this in the formal StackExchange rules. But each community makes its own informal rules, and here it seems to be an accepted practice. So go ahead, as I highly doubt that anyone will complain about it. (And nor should they, in my opinion.)

Comment: I've had extended comments that became answers. Truthfully, I think extended comments are fine as they often illustrate finer points not covered by the other answers.

Comment: Why not an "Extended comment" tag?   Seems like it might prove useful.

Comment: @Jagra because one cannot tag answers; only questions.

Comment: @OleksandrR. -- Ah, of course.  Must not be getting enough sleep these days.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is an extended comment, not an answer.

I searched my answers on the phrase "not an answer", a phrase I generally include in extended comments. I found 13 such answers. All but one had up votes. One them had 10 and another 13, although most had just one or two. So, yes, I would say that posting extended comments as answers is an accepted practice on *Mathematica*.SE.

One reason I resort to posting an extended comment as an answer is that I want to include graphics or many lines of code.